# Elliptic Curve Cryptography insecure when input does not lie on the curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am new to Elliptic Curve Cryptography and I was reading up on it online when I came across this [link](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/). It stated the following.

> Unfortunately, there is a gap between ECDLP difficulty and ECC security. None of these standards do a good job of ensuring ECC security. There are many attacks that break real-world ECC without solving ECDLP. The core problem is that if you implement the standard curves, chances are you're doing it wrong:
>
> 1. Your implementation produces incorrect results for some rare curve points.
> 2. Your implementation leaks secret data when the input isn't a curve point.
> 3. Your implementation leaks secret data through branch timing.
> 4. Your implementation leaks secret data through cache timing.

So, I was curious about the second point. How is it possible to leak secret data when the input isn't a curve point. I am assuming it means the base point(P) is not on the curve, but then how would P+P be calculated and how would it make the implementation insecure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attacks on schemes based on elliptic curves when the transmitted points are not on the curve](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34774/attacks-on-schemes-based-on-elliptic-curves-when-the-transmitted-points-are-not)

Comment: I'm looking at this and though the question seems like a duplicate, the answer there is somewhat terse and the reference is to a print book rather than an online resource. Perhaps we should allow this question to get more attention.

Comment: @MeirMaor My thoughts exactly. That is why, I didn't do anything about the possible duplicate comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you publish a public key $P = [n]G$ for a secret scalar $n$, where $G$ is the standard base point.

If you are willing to tell me $H([n]Q)$ given $Q = (x, y)$ for any coordinates $x$ and $y$ of my choice, then I can send you a point $Q$ of (say) order 2 on some *other* curve whose arithmetic law happens to coincide with the curve you meant to use, and learn $H([n]Q) = H([n \bmod 2]Q)$.

How does this work?  Suppose you use the short Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^3 + a_4 x + a_6$.  Since the addition law doesn't involve the constants $a_4$ or $a_6$ at all, and the doubling law involve only $a_4$, it turns out that you will happily compute scalar multiplication of points on *any* curve with the same $a_4$, so all I need to do is find some $a'_6$ whose curve has low-order points.

When I get back the answer, it is either $H([0]Q) = H(\mathcal O)$ or $H([1]Q) = H(Q)$, so by examining which one you returned, I can learn $n \bmod 2$.  The same applies if I send a point of order 3, 4, 5, *etc.*, and I can combine the results with the Chinese remainder theorem to interactively compute the discrete log $n$ of your public key $P = [n]G$ with your help.

Of course, if you expose the point $[n]Q$ instead of the hash $H([n]Q)$, then my task may be even easier!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks a lot! So, to counter this I should first check if the point lies on the curve and then proceed further right?

Comment: @InertFluid Better: For, _e.g._, DH, you can work exclusively in $x$ coordinates, which is cheaper anyway with the Montgomery ladder if it suffices to compute $H(x([n]P))$ given $x(P)$, so that the only curve you need to worry about is the quadratic twist, and you can choose curves so that ECDLP is hard on your curve _and_ on its quadratic twist, like Curve25519.  Caveat: in protocols beyond vanilla DH, the cofactor may cause trouble, so you may want to use Ristretto or Decaf.

Comment: @InertFluid But, in legacy systems that deal in both coordinates and/or don't support the Montgomery ladder, yes, you can check whether the point lies on the curve first.  It's better if you can avoid this, because in _legitimate_ usage, the logic will work whether or not you include the check, so it's easy to forget, and it's not free.